# MVC5 Injecting Runtime Data Into Layout View

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

In my layout view,I inject some cached data from service into layout view as below ;

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        @(Html.Raw(EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IStringService>().GetStringsJson()));
    </script>
```

It injects cached strings in json format. It does work ,however I had to use Service Locator and it is considered as anti-pattern.
What would be a better solution here ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem , i've used a global actionfilter and passed the data to the view in viewbag. Here's the code ;

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class GlobalValuesActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ICacheService _cacheService;

    public GlobalValuesActionFilter(ICacheService cacheService)
    {
        this._cacheService = cacheService;
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.UIStrings = _cacheService.GetUIStrings();
    }
}
```

Registering dependency(Autofac)

```
  builder.Register(c => new GlobalValuesActionFilter(c.Resolve<ICacheService>()))
                        .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>().InstancePerRequest();
```

And added following line to the view;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        @(Html.Raw(ViewBag.UIStrings));
    </script>
```